# Hibernate @preRemove doesn't work properly if on separate transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, model

It seems like I can not get @preRemove to work while in a separate session for some reason (if using the object from the previous session).

Below example works. As you can see, there is one session. It gets server object and than removes it. @preRemove works and sets null to all allocations.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

session.beginTransaction();

Server server = session.createQuery("from Server where id = :id", Server.class)
    .setParameter("id", "OpenSourcee")
    .getSingleResult();

session.getTransaction().commit();

session.beginTransaction();
session.remove(server);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Below is another example. I have two sessions. In session1, I use server object that i got from session. While doing session.remove(server), it fires @preRemove properly, but it does not save server_id = null for all allocations.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

session.beginTransaction();

Server server = session.createQuery("from Server where id = :id", Server.class)
    .setParameter("id", "OpenSourcee")
    .getSingleResult();

session.getTransaction().commit();

Session session1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.remove(server);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

There is a clear way to fix it. In the session I need to remove server, I can just create a new instance, based on ID from the one I got from previous session, but I'm looking for a way to avoid that... Any ideas? :)

Server model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "servers")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Server {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "external_id")
  private Long externalId = null;

  @Column(name = "external_uuid")
  private UUID externalUuid = null;

  @Column(name = "owner", nullable = false)
  private UUID owner;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "node")
  private Node node;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "server", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Allocation> allocations;

  @JoinColumn(name = "default_allocation", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @OneToOne()
  private Allocation defaultAllocation;

  @PreRemove
  private void preRemove() {
    for (Allocation allocation : allocations) {
      allocation.setServer(null);
    }
    setAllocations(null);
  }
}
```

Allocation object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "allocations")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Allocation {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "ip", nullable = false)
  private String ip;

  @Column(name = "port", nullable = false)
  private Integer port;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "node")
  private Node node;

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "server_id")
  private Server server;
}
```

Comment: define `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` for `allocations` assocication.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work @AndreyB.Panfilov. Seems like the only way to use this object in another session is to generate it inside this session separately by using for example `server = session.get(previousServer.getId(), Server.class)`... I've read something about session.update, but that doesn't work as well...

Comment: Did you provide a real code or just a PoC? `session1` sees both `server` entity and it's associations (list of `Allocation`'s in you case) as detached objects, that in turn means changes in `Allocation` do not trigger subsequent save - those entities are not managed by `session1`, however, when HBN is running in JPA mode it denies deleting detached entities - in case of JPA in order to delete entity we need to either merge it first or retrieve it's persistent instance by id (workaround you proposed) - that caused me to think the real code is "bit different"